# Force enigmail to sign with a specific subkey

Tags: email, gpg, thunderbird, enigmail

I have a GPG key with multiple signing subkeys and I want to force enigmail to sign email with a specified subkey. [GPG can be forced to sign with a specific subkey](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Specify-a-User-ID.html#Specify-a-User-ID) by appending the characted "!" after the subkey id, but engimail does not appear to have any support for that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently enigmail developers [deliberately decided](http://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/forum/support/thread/37b7a5c8/) to not support this possibility. A workaround is to manually modifying the file `pref.js` adding the exclamation mark after the key id specified in lines like

```
user_pref("mail.identity.id1.pgpkeyId", "0x089380E4!");
```

This has to be done once for every configured identity.

**EDIT** I discovered a problem with this workaround: enigmail will use the same subkey for self-encrypting emails. Since the specified subkey will (probably) be a signing subkey (rather than an encrypting subkey), sending encrypted emails will fail if you adopt this workaround.